# Populating Dropdown HTML Menu with MySQL Query Results

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm attempting to populate an HTML dropdown menu with the results of a MySQL query. The query is running fine and not throwing any errors, but for some odd reason the results won't display correctly.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE itemName LIKE 'Processors:%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to query CPU parts");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $option .= "<option value='{$row['itemName']}'></option>";
        }
?>
    <select name="cpu"><? echo $option; ?></select>
```

I'm pretty sure it lies somewhere in the `$option .= ... ;` but it I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: it should be like this..  $option .= "<option value='$row['itemValue']'>$row['itemName']</option>";

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the value to be shown in dropdown

try this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $option .= "<option value='{$row['itemName']}'>{$row['itemName']}</option>";
    }
```

I saw that you are using short tags here

```
<select name="cpu"><? echo $option; ?></select>
```

please make sure you have short tag enabled in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

You need to initialize $option and print the value to be shown in the dropdown

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE itemName LIKE 'Processors:%'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to query CPU parts");
$option = "";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $option .= "<option value='{$row['itemName']}'>{$row['itemName']}</option>";

}
?>

<select name="cpu"><? echo $option; ?></select>
```

Comment: I thought PHP didn't require a variable to be declared prior to use?

Comment: In this case yes, because when you do $foo .= "value" you are doing $foo = $foo + "value"; If $foo is not declared a notice error is showed

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forget to add a value inside `<option></option>` field you only set value for fetching `$_POST[]` but not for viewing. :D

Also seeing  `$option` variable to be concatenated seems that you already declared it at first
if not you need to probably declared it first.cause this may result to error undefined variable.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE itemName LIKE 'Processors:%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to query CPU parts");
    $option = '';
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $option .= '<option value='.$row['itemName'].'>'. $row['itemName'].'</option>';
        }
?>
    <select name="cpu"><?php echo $option; ?></select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Forgot the simplest part:

$aa .= "{$row['itemName']}";

I needed to add the actual label to be displayed between the option tags :)